# Why is margin: 0 0 0 auto not working without display: flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

Using the below code, I am trying to take the Follow button at the right of the screen. For that, I am using margin: 0 0 0 auto for the .follow class. It works when I use display: flex in the parent element (here is header element), but when I remove display: flex from the parent, it comes down my name. Why is it happening?

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Montserrat, monospace;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.profile-pic {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px;
}

.name {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.username {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.follow {
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="Azraf Khan Zarif" class="profile-pic">
  <div class="name">Azraf Khan Zarif</div>
  <div class="username">@Zarif</div>
  <button class="follow">Follow</button>
</header>
```

Comment: Try `float: right;`

Comment: Because `margin: 0 0 0 auto;` is for right aligning in-flow **block-level** elements and your button is **inline-level**.

Answer (score 0):

when you put `display: flex;` it also add `flex-direction: row;` as default behavior of a flex.

because of which all your children inside `<header>` were rendered as a single row.

also adding `margin: 0 0 0 auto` to your follow button moves it to the right corner inside the whole flex row area.
if you remove it you will see `Follow` button shows up just next to `"@Zarif"` text

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because that’s how the **Flexible Box Module** works. Putting the `display: flex` instruction in the `header` element makes it a *flexbox* container, with the default values of `flex-direction: row` and `justify-content: flex-start`. This, in conjunction with `margin: 0 0 0 auto`, puts the button on the right.

Without flexbox, you could achieve the same result wth:

```
header {
    position: relative;
    ...
}

.follow {
    position: abolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    ...
}
```

Doing so, the button would be placed in the top-right corner because now it’d be positioned according to “parent coordinates”: the code would tell the button to move `0px` away from the top, and `0px` away from the right.